Rubocop doesn't run and returns `Connection refused` instead
I can't run bundle exec rubocop -a because of the following error:
/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/rubocop-1.65.1/lib/rubocop/server/client_command/base.rb:28:in `initialize': Connection refused - connect(2) for "127.0.0.1" port 63008 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)

I've tried different solutions like stopping the server, updating the gem, reinstalling them, bundle update and so on and nothing works :(
I've noticed it's two different ports: 57622 vs 63008:
The error says that

RuboCop server (57622) is already running.

When I run rubocop -v I receive the same error with a preline

RuboCop version incompatibility found, RuboCop server restarting...

Tried to run it from the terminal separately or from Rubymine – doesn't matter, same output.
which rubocop returns /Users/myuser/.asdf/shims/rubocop 
I don't know what else to do..
The full log:
 from /Users/myuser/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/rubocop-1.65.1/lib/rubocop/server/client_command/base.rb:28:in `open'
    from /Users/myuser/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/rubocop-1.65.1/lib/rubocop/server/client_command/base.rb:28:in `send_request'
    from /Users/myuser/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/rubocop-1.65.1/lib/rubocop/server/client_command/exec.rb:21:in `run'
    from /Users/myuser/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/rubocop-1.65.1/exe/rubocop:12:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/myuser/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.3.1/bin/rubocop:25:in `load'
    from /Users/myuser/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.3.1/bin/rubocop:25:in `<main>'


So rubocop --stop-server or the likes of it didn't help. What helped is killing running pods manually:
ps aux | grep 'rubocop --server'
sudo kill -9 PID

And then after running bundle exec rubocop -a the server process will restart automatically.
